# JavaScript Ile Picking the process

Tags: javascript, math

wrong   = **25.000 + 123 = 148**
success = **25.000 + 123 = 25123**

```
urunun_fiyati = '25.000';
toplam_fiyat  = '123';
toplam_fiyat = (urunun_fiyati + toplam_fiyat);
```

doing the wrong operation

Comment: 25.000 === 25.  In JavaScript a dot means decimal places, not a comma separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
urunun_fiyati = 25000;
toplam_fiyat  = 123;
toplam_fiyat = (urunun_fiyati + toplam_fiyat);
```